# operator== on C++ structs with conversion operators

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the set of `==` operators that are explored when comparing two structs where there is no operator `==` defined. In this case the built-in operator for `ints` is used for conversion. However this does not work for nested classes for example, i.e. if `Y` contained a class that defined an `==` operator. Is this only applicable when a struct can be converted to a built-in type unambiguously?

```cpp
struct X {
    int x;
};

struct Y {
    int y;
    operator int() {
        return y;
    }
};

int main() {
//    bool val {X{} == X{}}; // does not compile
    bool val {Y{} == Y{}}; // works
}
```

Comment: *Is this only applicable when a struct can be converted to a built-in type unambiguously?* -- Honest opinion -- as soon as you use conversion operators in a class, the more chance of the code not compiling due to ambiguity errors, or the code taking a different path than you expect.  That's why the conversion operators are seldomly used in the C++ standard library.

Comment: Note : implicit conversions (of any type) might seem useful but can also bite you back (in large projects).  Watch this [C++ weekly, implicit conversion must go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T97QJ0KBaBU&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes and structs don't have equality (or any) operators by default. You need to overload whatever is needed for your implementation and specify the comparisons explicitly.

```cpp
struct X {
    int x;

    bool operator==(const X& other) const { return x == other.x; }
    bool operator!=(const X& other) const { return y != other.x; }
    ...

};
```

That's true for every comparison operator (==, !=, <, >, <=, >=). That is unless you use C++20, in which you can specify the default <=> operator and have the compiler generate them for you (ofc the more members your struct has, the more complicated this gets; the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) on comparisons are a good read).

```cpp
#include <compare>

struct X {
    int x;

    auto operator<=>(const X&) const = default;
};
```